# Angularjs 1.2: include template in repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I am moving to the last version of angularjs (1.2), and now it seems that i cant include templates in the repeater:

http://plnkr.co/edit/K7n9sNhXe4z99VMSqTlk?p=preview

I can use directive with templateUrl but is there a way to do this with ng-include only ?

Thanks.

**Note**: this works with the latest stable angularjs version (1.0.7)

---

**EDIT**: Error log (latest Chrome version) on each repeat element:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:3321:22
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:199:18)
    at Object.enter (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:3320:9)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:15947:24
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:6277:11
    at wrappedCallback (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:9042:59)
    at wrappedCallback (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:9042:59)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:9128:26
    at Object.Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:9953:28)
    at Object.Scope.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js:9809:23)
```

Comment: It looks like a bug, file a bug report please.

Comment: @sza: edited with error log.

Comment: i am not seeing the error you posted, but I see the render doesn't work. it is a bug i think.

Comment: theres a whole section on includes in the new documentation all about trusted sources. It's quite complicated. http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.$sce

Comment: Ok, tried to disable the service (http://plnkr.co/edit/brpArc?p=preview) but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

spooky-giraffe (v 1.2) is not a production release. Many of the jsfiddle and plunker examples found in the docs.angularjs.org pages no longer work since those examples auto-updated to version 1.2.

There are many feature updates and bug fixes in version 1.2, including a complete rewrite of ngAnimate, but still much work to be done before it becomes a stable release.

Comment: Ok i'll stick with the 1.0.7 then.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in the next release of angular.

I cloned the frameowkr, packaged it and added it to the plnkr, Here you go:
http://plnkr.co/edit/k6P4Yv19bUV0BC4VBL69?p=preview

The PR that reverted the breaking changes:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3640