# AngularJS 1.2 ngInclude inside ngIf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm running into some odd behavior when putting an ngInclude inside an ngIf or ngSwitch.

For example, take the following:

```
<button ng-click="showIncTemplate = !showIncTemplate">Toggle Included Template</button>
<button ng-click="showInlineTemplate = !showInlineTemplate">Toggle Inline Template</button>

<div ng-if="showIncTemplate">
    <p>Included template:</p>
    <div ng-include="'template.html'"></div>
</div>

<div ng-if="showInlineTemplate">
    <h1>Inline Template</h1>
</div>
```

(http://plnkr.co/edit/gULbwnKb0gQS8DWz0V6U)

The buttons toggle an options to render the divs that follow. The inline example behaves as expected, with the content appearing or disappearing on click.

The div with the child include seems not to include the template when first drawn, but then includes it repeatedly on every subsequent redraw.

What's going on here? I do see some breaking changes around ngInclude, is there some other way I should be doing this? Or is this a bug in Angular?

Edit:

It looks like this is already in the angularjs github issue tracker:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3627

Comment: It could be a bug. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276876/angularjs-1-2-include-template-in-repeat

Comment: Yeah, found it in the github issues. I guess I'll be waiting a little longer for 1.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They've fixed it in this snapshot:

http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/

Comment: Sice nicholas did not provide version, I googled and found out that it was fixed supposedly in 1.2.0-rc.3